# How to move a row to another column based on cell value and then delete that row

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel sheet I would like for it to move an entire row from Sheet1 ("Action Register") to sheet2 ("Completed") if the word "closed" is in the row in column J, and then delete the row on the first sheet. 
This is the code that I have so far, but it doesn't copy all of the "closed" rows from "Action Register" to the "Completed" sheet, it only copies one of the rows and then all of them get deleted. Can someone help point out where I've gone wrong?
Thanks

```
Sub Copyx()

    Sheets("Action Register").Select

    RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To RowCount

        Range("J" & i).Select

        check_value = ActiveCell

        If check_value = "closed" Or check_value = "closed" Then

            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy

            Sheets("Completed").Select

            RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Range("A" & RowCount + 1).Select

            ActiveSheet.Paste

            Sheets("Action Register").Select

        End If
    Next


'-

    Dim c As Range

    Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("J1", ActiveSheet.Range("J50000").End(xlUp))

    Do

        Set c = SrchRng.Find("closed", LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete

    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Move the row to another worksheet, but it's looking for the word "closed" in column J to trigger the move

Comment: I have tried those, and haven't been able to get one to work properly, this is the closest I've got (with the above code), which works besides the fact that it is only copying one of the entries and not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this cut and insert to achieve this.

```
Sub Copyx()

Sheets("Action Register").Select

RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To RowCount

Range("J" & i).Select

check_value = ActiveCell

If check_value = "closed" Or check_value = "closed" Then

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut

Sheets("Completed").Select

RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A" & RowCount + 1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Sheets("Action Register").Select

End If
Next
'-

Dim c As Range

Dim SrchRng

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("J1", ActiveSheet.Range("J50000").End(xlUp))

Do

Set c = SrchRng.Find("closed", LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete

Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```